# Invalid Credentials for Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

This weekend I started a new project that involved the Google Drive API. I was able to query the Files and Permissions resources successfully using a service account.

Then on Monday, without making any changes to my code, I started getting 401 **Invalid Credentials** on every request. I am still able to query the Admin SDK API with the same service account credentials.

I'm using the Python Google API client. I made sure to include all the scopes listed in the API documentation in my request in Python. I have granted domain wide delegation to the service account along with all the necessary scopes.

I get the same error if I use a service account or if I use `OAuth 2.0` and use an admin user to grant authorization. I even get the error when I use the API explorer on the documentation page (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list for example). This is the response I repeatedly get:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

Any ideas for other approaches I can try to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

There is a page in [Google Drive API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#resolve_a_401_error_invalid_credentials) about all possible errors of the API. You can take a look about the `401` error:

> A 401 error indicates that the access token you're using is either expired or invalid. This error can also be caused by missing authorization for the requested scopes.

> To fix this error, refresh the access token using the long-lived refresh token. If this fails, direct the user through the OAuth flow, as described in [Authorizing Your App with Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth).

So a list of things that you need to do:

- Make sure you are [refreshing your access token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#5.-refresh-the-access-token,-if-necessary.)
- Check again [the scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes) used

Also reading about the [Oauth2 workflow in Google API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server) could be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out someone had turned off Google Drive for my organization. Once we enabled it, the API calls began working again.